# Java java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')'

Tags: java, regex

Quiero eliminar urls de un texto que leo por fichero usando regex, pero no me funciona porque se genera una excepción que está en el título, he buscado por SO y los posts que encuentro hablan de que hay que escapar los paréntesis, es lo que he hecho, pero no me funciona.

Código:

```
public String eliminaUrl(String cadena) throws Exception{

    String urlPattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(cadena);
    int i = 0;
    while (m.find()) {//lo va haciendo caracter a caracter
        cadena = cadena.replaceAll(m.group(i),"");
        i++;
    }

    return cadena;
}
```

Error:

```
 java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 19
```

la línea del  input donde se genera: `http://otherinboxcom)`

Se agradece ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Lo mejor seria que dieras unos ejemplos de las cadenas que quieres eliminar para poder realizar pruebas locales y ayudarte con el error

Comment: @RobertoEMoran En el post del ejercicio hay un ejemplo: http://otherinboxcom)

Comment: aquí pongo más  http://www.formspring.me/LMT23"  http://tinyurl.com/8woa3j   http://bkite.com/02RHw

Comment: He dejado una respuesta espero y te solucione el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno según los ejemplo que proporcionas y lo que he entendido lo he resuelto con los siguientes cambios :

```
 public String eliminaUrl(String cadena) throws Exception{

    String urlPattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(cadena);
    // Elimine el indice de los grupos ya que no me fue necesario utilizarlo
    // para los ejemplos, pero eso queda tu criterio si lo necesitas.
    while (m.find()) {
        cadena = cadena.replace(m.group(0),"");// y cambie el replaceAll por replace
    }

    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: Vale, gracias, el método group() en Java devuelve la parte de la cadena que casó con el match no? yo lo que estaba haciendo era reemplazando con group(i) carácter a carácter , ¿sabes por qué fallaba eso? .Saludos

Comment: Con lo del group lo que sucede es que 0 es el grupo completo, entonces no tendrías necesidad de de ir remplazando grupo por grupo porque 0 ya remplaza la cadena completa, y con el error de replaceAll la verdad hasta a mi me parece un error muy extraños y poco descriptivo, al menos yo  no te podría dar una respuesta de porque sucede.